Split *ngFor data into 2 columns
I have this HTML:
<div class="w-full flex justify-center">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="flex w-1/2">
    <span>{{item.label}}</span>
    <span>{{item.value}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

This way, the HTML in UI is displayed as:
LABEL 1 - VALUE 1 | LABEL 2 - VALUE 2
LABEL 3 - VALUE 3 | LABEL 4 - VALUE 4
LABEL 5 - VALUE 5 | LABEL 6 - VALUE 6

I need to display data like this:
LABEL 1 - VALUE 1 | LABEL 4 - VALUE 4
LABEL 2 - VALUE 2 | LABEL 5 - VALUE 5
LABEL 3 - VALUE 3 | LABEL 6 - VALUE 6

I´ve been trying to find a working solution but without luck. Can you suggest a working solution?

did you try flex-column?

what did you try? and what didn't work with the solution you tried?

Is your items array static or dynamic, can it have more than 6 elements ?

Take the data and split it in half. Save one half to variable a and the other half to variable b. Then loop over each of the variables independently.

Chunk the items array into half.
chunkedItems: any[][] = [];

let halfIndex = Math.floor(this.items.length / 2);
this.chunkedItems = [
  this.items.slice(0, halfIndex),
  this.items.slice(halfIndex, this.items.length),
  ];
}

And structure the flex containers as below:
<div class="w-full flex flex-wrap justify-center">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let chunks of chunkedItems; let i = index">
    <div class="flex flex-col w-1/2">
      <div *ngFor="let item of chunks" class="flex">
        <span>{{item.label}}</span> -
        <span>{{item.value}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>

Demo @ StackBlitz

Just a note: floor will add more items to the second column, and ceil will add more items to the first column when there are an odd number of items.

Try this code

 
    
        {{item.label}} - {{item.value}}
    
  
    
        {{item.label}} - {{item.value}}
    



@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  items = [
    { label: 'LABEL 1', value: 'VALUE 1' },
    { label: 'LABEL 2', value: 'VALUE 2' },
    { label: 'LABEL 3', value: 'VALUE 3' },
    { label: 'LABEL 4', value: 'VALUE 4' },
    { label: 'LABEL 5', value: 'VALUE 5' },
    { label: 'LABEL 6', value: 'VALUE 6' }
  ];

  firstColumnItems() {
    return this.items.filter((item, index) => index % 3 === 0 || index % 3 === 1);
  }

  secondColumnItems() {
    return this.items.filter((item, index) => index % 3 === 2);
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="w-full flex justify-center">
   
    <div class="w-1/2" *ngFor="let item of firstColumnItems()">
        <span>{{item.label}}</span> - <span>{{item.value}}</span>
    </div>
  
    <div class="w-1/2" *ngFor="let item of secondColumnItems()">
        <span>{{item.label}}</span> - <span>{{item.value}}</span>
    </div>
</div>



